# Simple "Hello World" code does not appear on Command Prompt

Tags: c++, std, codeblocks, iostream

So I have been watching a tutorial (here: https://youtu.be/yKATaptz3Dc) to complete my first line of code. My code is identical to the one in the video yet nothing appears on my console. I'm assuming there is some settings issue in my version of Code::Blocks but I have no idea where to begin. Ideas?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: how about adding a `cin.get();` at the end before `return`?

Comment: ...but before `return 0;`

Comment: @PcAF: Valid point, updated.

Comment: Try in the command line (e.g. bash) `g++ hello.cpp && ./a.out`  It is your IDE's problem.

Comment: Sorry, none of this fixed my problem. Again, the code in the video worked just fine so I have a feeling there really is no code-based solution to getting this to function. (really don't even know why I came here). Sorry

Comment: A few minor comments: One usually put a space between `#include` and the first angle bracket. The `return 0;` is redundant in `main()`. `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to get into - `using std::cout;` to just pull in what you need or explicitly using `std::cout` is much better in the long run. You probably want to put a `\n` after "Hello World!" To print a newline after the text.

Comment: If this is on windows try disabling your antivirus. aVast is known to prevent unknown code from executing.

Comment: ***Sorry, none of this fixed my problem.*** You could help by telling us what OS you are running. And exactly what you tried. @gongzhitaao gave you commands that would work on linux but it would not work from a cmd.exe  window on windows.

Comment: ***I have a feeling there really is no code-based solution to getting this to function.*** The code is not the problem. There could be several issues causing this to not work however you have to describe the exact problem otherwise we have to play guess what is wrong..

Answer (score 4):

This is an *exceedingly* common problem, and almost always goes to this issue:

**You are executing your program incorrectly.**

A console program expects to be run from a console. Yet you are probably running it from your IDE or double-clicking its icon from Explorer, which causes Windows to *create* a new console, run your program, *and then destroy* the console. Sometimes you will see the new console window flash briefly on the screen, sometimes you will not.

To run the program correctly, use Explorer to find your program's exe, click on the location bar at the top and type "cmd" and press Enter. You'll get a console with the current directory at your exe. Type the name of your exe file. Enjoy the output.

Another common response is to add code that tries to do a "Press enter to continue..." kind of thing before `return 0;`, but that is really not the correct way to do it.

Hope this helps.